# Create a list based on two other lists

Tags: python, list, iterable

What am I doing wrong? I am getting the error:

IndexError: list index out of range

I want new_col = [0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0]

```
starts = [1,5,9,13]
ends = [3,7,10,16]

new_col = []

check = 0
start_idx = 0
end_idx = 0

for i in range(20):
    if i == starts[start_idx]:
        check += 1
        new_col.append(check)
        start_idx += 1
        continue
    elif i == ends[end_idx]:
        check -= 1
        new_col.append(check)
        end_idx += 1
        continue
    else:
        new_col.append(check)
        continue
```

Comment: After `start_idx` or `end_idx` reaches the end of its corresponding list, *you keep checking that index*.  To make this approach work, you'd have to write the tests like `if start_idx < len(starts) and i == starts[start_idx]:`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear to me exactly where the state machine is breaking, but it seems unnecessarily tricky.  Rather than attempting to debug and fix it I'd just iterate over the ranges like this:

```
>>> starts = [1,5,9,13]
>>> ends = [3,7,10,16]
>>> new_col = [0] * 20
>>> for start, end in zip(starts, ends):
...     for i in range(start, end):
...         new_col[i] = 1
... 
>>> new_col
[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: To avoid the second nested `for` loop I'd just replace it with `new_col[start:end] = [1] * (end-start)`. But otherwise great solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `start_idx` and `end_idx` are getting incremented until they're off the end of your list.

```
starts = [1,5,9,13]
ends = [3,7,10,16]
```

should be

```
starts = [1,5,9,13,21]
ends = [3,7,10,16,21]
```